# How to remove scrolling on web page

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, scroller

I can't figure out how to remove scrolling from this webpage: http://www.totalperimeter.com

Resizing the image did not work nor did removing the scroll bar or setting overflow: hidden; and height: 100%;. (Using CSS on the body and html tags).

Please help

Answer (score 1):

On firefox, I able to remove the scroll by doing this:

```
'overflow': 'hidden',
'height': '100%'
```

On the body tag of the page.

Note that the page is not importing any JQuery. I had to it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the height on the div with classes: 'section mcb-section full-screen'.

Currently it is set to 1090px (e.g. changing it to '100vh' (100% of view height) gets rid of the vertical scrolling).